# SQL : how to add condition on inner select

Tags: sql, select

```
1. links: link_id, road
2. roads: road, code
2. admin_classes: code, admin_class, priority
```

So, for ONE LINK_ID I have several codes and several admin_class+priority raws
But in result set i need only one row for each link_id:
 link_id and admin_class, that refers to min priority.
I try to make sql statement, like following:

```
select l.link_id, ac.admin_class, min(ac.priority)
from base.links as l
inner join base.admin_classes as ac
on ac.code=l.code
where ac.admin_class<>0
```

but, firstly,  it does not work and it is not that i need. I want only two columns in result set - link_id and admin_class

Then I try following:

```
select l.link_id, (select ac.admin_class from base.admin_classes as ac where ac.code=l.code
order by ac.priority limit 1) as admin_class from base.links as l
```

It is right, but I don know how to add condition on inner select, I only need raws with admin_class<>0

I use PostgreSql 8.3

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with postgresql, but I'm guessing the original query doesn't work becuse you have a `min()` aggregation function with no `group by`

Nevertheless, the following should work if you don't need the `min()`:

```
select l.link_id, ac.admin_class
from base.links as l
inner join base.admin_classes as ac
        on ac.code=l.code
       and ac.admin_class<>0
```

Otherwise, try:

```
select l.link_id, ac.admin_class, min(ac.priority)
from base.links as l
inner join base.admin_classes as ac
        on ac.code=l.code
       and ac.admin_class<>0
group by l.link_id, ac.admin_class
```

Comment: Sorry, i tried to simplify and wrote incorrect)) we have followng table 1: link_id, code.  table2: id, code, road. table3: road, admin_class, priority. So we have several roads for one link_id and several rows from table 3 for one link_id, but we want to get link_id + admin_class with min priority)

Comment: Thanks for answer) But i need only two column in result set because i use it in imsert clouse (( And the last statement will returns followng raws 1-2-2, 1-3-2, 1-4-2 for one link_id=1, but i need only one row for one link_id

Answer (score 1):

I believe you should do two things.

**1st Create a view called viewAdminRoads**

```
CREATE VIEW viewAdminRoads
AS
SELECT 
roads.code,
roads.road,
admin_classes.admin_class,
admin_classes.priority
FROM roads 
INNER JOIN admin_classes
        ON roads.road
         = admin_classes.road
WHERE admin_classes.priority <> 0
```

*Creating this view simplifies the entire process*

**2nd Create your selection**

```
SELECT
link.link_id,
MIN(viewAdminRoads.priority) as priority
FROM links
INNER JOIN viewAdminRoads
        ON links.code
         = viewAdminRoads.code
GROUP BY link.link_id
```

Remember, views are your friend.

Comment: I agree, but our project politics does not accept views. But i am already resolve my problem using sub select. Thank you for your answer

Answer (score 0):

This is not working?

```
inner join base.admin_classes as ac 
on ac.code=l.code and ac.admin_class<>0
```

Answer (score 0):

Well i don't know much about PostgreSql, but this is how it's done with T-SQL:

```
select l.link_id, ac.admin_class, min(ac.priority)
from base.links as l
inner join base.admin_classes as ac
on ac.code=l.code
group by l.link_id, ac.admin_class
having ac.admin_class <> 0
```

Comment: I believe the 'having' clause is only really necessary when you're using it in conjunction with the aggregate itself. Changing it the 'where' and moving the line above the 'group by' will also work :-)

Comment: I mistaked( I have several raws from admin_classes for one link_id so your request returns smth like this: 1-2-2, 1-3-2 and ect. But I need only one row for one link id and only two columns because i use it in insert clause